# Reclaim unused space from a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, in one of our databases, we have a big database table that's using over 1.2 TB of space. It has about 200 GB of actual data but over **1 TB** of unused space.

This happened over 2 years as old time series data was deleted from this table daily and new data was inserted daily.

We do not expect for the table size to increase much going forward.

I am looking for the best way to reclaim unused space from this table without taking the database or table offline, and without causing too much CPU overhead.

Comment: If your table doesn't have a clustered index (as it should), see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186572/how-to-reclaim-the-storage-space-used-by-a-heap).

Answer (score 2):

I think for this you'll need to use [DBCC Shrinkfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), possibly in several incremental steps.

First see if *truncateonly* has an acceptable effect - it depends on how the data is distributed within the file

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'Tablename' , truncateonly)
```

If the file does not shrink sufficiently you can specify a target size to shrink to in MB eg

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'Tablename' , 256000)
```

You can monitor the impact on performance while this executes and stop it if need be, resuming again as appropriate.